# Django Rest Framework doesn't render generics.ListAPIView, model with GM2MField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

First, sorry for my english, but it's not my native language.

I have the next problem: 
I'm working in a Django app, I have a model like this:

```
class AlarmEvent(models.Model):
# Alarm types

USER = 'US'
DEVICE = 'DV'
NO_DEVICE = 'ND'

ALARM_CHOICES = (
    (USER, 'User'),
    (DEVICE, 'Device'),
    (NO_DEVICE, 'No-Device')
)
    alarm = models.ForeignKey(Alarm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    alarm_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ALARM_CHOICES,       default=USER)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    content_type = GM2MField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='description', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alarm_type + '-' + str(self.pk)
```

As you can see, I'm using GM2MField() from third-party app: [django-gm2m](http://django-gm2m.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to have generic M2M relations.
For this model I have the following serializer:

```
class AlarmEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AlarmEvent
        fields = ('id', 'alarm', 'alarm_type', 'created', 'finished', 'device', 'variables', 'content_type', 'description')
```

I'm using this view:

```
class AlarmEventList(generics.ListAPIView):

    ''' List AlarmEvents by filters, or create a new AlarmEvent '''

    serializer_class = AlarmEventSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_class = AlarmEventFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        ''' Getting events which the user is subscribed '''
        #TODO: Fix api/alarms/events endpoint
        alarms = Subscription.objects.filter(Q(user__in=[self.request.user]) | Q(group__in=self.request.user.groups.all())).values_list('alarm', flat=True)

        return AlarmEvent.objects.filter(alarm__in=alarms)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ''' Create new event '''
        serializer = AlarmEventSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My problem is the next error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alarms/events/
>
> Django Version: 2.0.3 Python Version: 3.6.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['alarms',  'fotuto_models',  'rest_framework',  'django_filters', 
>   'guardian',  'corsheaders',  'django.contrib.admin', 
>   'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'gm2m', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Template error: In template
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal/select_multiple.html,
>   error at line 15    'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'    5 : 
>   6 :     7 :   {% if field.label %}    8 :
>       9 :       {{ field.label }}    10 :
>       11 :   {% endif %}    12 :     13 :       14 :         15 :        {% for select in field.iter_options %} 
>   16 :         {% if select.start_option_group %}    17 :
>       18 :         {% elif
>   select.end_option_group %}    19 :               20 :
>   {% else %}    21 :           {{
>   select.display_text }}    22 :         {% endif %}    23 :
>   {% empty %}    24 :           {{ no_items }}    25 : 
>   {% endfor %}
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     35.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     156.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     106.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in
>   rendered_content
>     72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in render
>     718.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in get_context
>     691.             'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in get_rendered_html_form
>     514.             return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in render_form_for_serializer
>     524.             {'style': {'template_pack': 'rest_framework/horizontal'}}
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in render
>     375.         return template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     175.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     314.                 return nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/library.py" in
>   render
>     192.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py"
>   in render_field
>     90.     return renderer.render_field(field, style)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in render_field
>     354.         return template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     175.                     return self._render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render_annotated
>     910.             return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     161.                 values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in resolve
>     676.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in resolve
>     802.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _resolve_lookup
>     864.                             current = current()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py"
>   in iter_options
>     534.             self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py"
>   in get_choices
>     522.         return self.child_relation.get_choices(cutoff)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py"
>   in get_choices
>     194.             for item in queryset
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
>   **iter**
>     272.         self._fetch_all()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
>   _fetch_all
>     1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
>   **iter**
>     53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch,
>   chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in execute_sql
>     1053.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in as_sql
>     446.             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in pre_sql_setup
>     50.         self.setup_query()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in setup_query
>     40.             self.query.get_initial_alias()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in get_initial_alias
>     886.             alias = self.join(BaseTable(self.get_meta().db_table, None))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in get_meta
>     284.         return self.model._meta
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/alarms/events/ Exception Value:
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

It happens when I go to my AlarmEvent endpoint in a browser...I'm using generics.ListAPIView to render it, but Django does not render it. It's interesting because when I use Postman for example, I get a response...

The error doesn't happen for a particular object.

---

*localhost:8000/api/alarms/events/*  -> Doesn't render, but I get response and 200 status
*localhost:8000/api/alarms/events/2* -> For a particular object, It render and get response

Comment: Can you post the view you are using ?

Comment: @PaddyPopeye Done.  I have been working on it and I realized that this happen because my API endpoint for this model using Django Rest Framework have POST option, if I eliminate POST method, it render. The thing is that I can't post and object with the gm2m list empty, and this is the reason because it can render it. I'm talking with repo's owner [link](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/django-gm2m/issues/38/django-rest-framework-doesnt-render) <- **here**